# Seeking good source of FOSS graphics/components for Process Control/Scada

Tags: silverlight, process-control, scada

I want some whizz-bang browser graphics to impress management - for SCADA/process control.  Until now I have been worrying about which technology - to SilverLight or not to SilverLight?

But, really, the technology doesn't matter too much when I am only concerned about appearance. So, is there any good source of royalty free graphics or animated components - which maybe take their values from a database and are aimed at industrial process control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](http://www.iocomp.com) doesn't impress them, I don't know what will. ;-)

Comment: +1 Well, you certainly understood what I wanted, thanks. It's 11:30pm here & I just got in & peeked at it - off to bed now, will check it out fully in the morning.  Thanks again

Comment: +1 and the answer. You seem very knowledgable in this area. That's three of my questions you have answered. You can probably expect some more ;-)